# Trying to Set variable Dim'd as Range to list of 278 entries in one column

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my code:

```
Dim rngNames As Range
--- other code
Sheets("MDs Scorecard").Select
Range("E8").Select
**Set rngNames = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select  <<--**
Selection.Copy
--- other code
```

The ** line results in Run-time error '424': Object required.

How can I set a variable Dim'd as Range to a Range starting at a defined cell and ending at the last cell containing a value?

Answer (score 0):

Close, just remove .select from that line. To set it as an object you don't want to select it.

Also you can get rid of the select on E8 by combining into the set like so:

```
Sub testRng()
Dim rngNames As Range
Set rngNames = Range(Range("E8"), Range("E8").End(xlToRight))
rngNames.Select
End Sub
```

So yours would be something like:

```
Dim rngNames As Range
--- other code
Sheets("MDs Scorecard").Select
Set rngNames = Range(Range("E8"), Range("E8").End(xlToRight))
Selection.Copy
--- other code
```

Note, you can also get rid of the sheet selection but it depends what you are doing after the copy, you can qualify it like so:

```
Set rngNames = Sheets("MDs Scorecard").Range(Sheets("MDs Scorecard").Range("E8"), Sheets("MDs Scorecard").Range("E8").End(xlToRight))
```

Comment: Thanks for the better way to Set rngNames.

Answer (score 0):

Dan was faster than me in writing a correct answer.  However, I think there are some extra points that are worth making so I am posting my answer.

Your title says you want to select a column but you are attempting to select a row.  Did you mean to use `xlDown` rather than `xlToRight`.

You say you want the selection to end at the last cell containing a value.  Neither `xlDown` nor `xlToRight` are guaranteed to do that.

`End(xlDown)`, `End(xlUp)`, `End(xlToRight)` are `End(xlToLeft)` are the VBA equivalents of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd>.  I suggest you place the cursor in E8 and try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> with:

- No value in E8 or in remainder of row.
- Value in E8 but not in the remainder of the row.
- Values in E8 and E9.  The state of the remainder of row is unimportant.
- Values in E8 and E10.  The state of the remainder of row is unimportant.

I doubt you will get the effect you expect in all cases.

Starting from the bottom row or rightmost column and moving towards E8 is more likely to give you the effect you seek.

**Choice 1**

`Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select` extends a selection and selects the extended range

```
Sheets("MDs Scorecard").Select
Range("E8").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.Copy
```

**Choice 2**

This code sets rngName and then pastes its contents to the range starting in H10.

```
Dim rngNames As Range

Sheets("MDs Scorecard").Select
Range("E8").Select
Set rngNames = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight))
rngNames.Copy

Range("H10").Select     ' Example paste of selected range
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

**Choice 3**

This code is more likely to give you the effect you seek and avoids using `Select`.  Avoiding `Select` is good practice because it is a slow command and if you are switching between worksheets it can become very confusing.  I show setting `rngNames` to both the row and the column since I am not clear which you want.  I use Debug.Print to show the effect of the statements.

```
With Sheets("MDs Scorecard")

  ' If you want to select row 8, this is the equivalent of placing the cursor
  ' in the rightmost column and moving left until a value is reached.
  colLast = .Cells(8, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  Debug.Print "Last column " & colLast

  ' If you want to select column E, this is the equivalent of placing the cursor
  ' in the bottom row and moving up until a value is reached.
  rowLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
  Debug.Print "Last row " & rowLast

  ' This sets rngNames to the row from E8 to the last column with a value
  Set rngNames = .Range(.Cells(8, "E"), .Cells(8, colLast))
  Debug.Print rngNames.Address      ' To show the specified range

  ' This sets rngNames to the column from E8 to the last row with a value
  Set rngNames = .Range(.Cells(8, "E"), .Cells(rowLast, "E"))
  Debug.Print rngNames.Address      ' To show the specified range

  ' This copies the range to the row or column starting in H10
  rngNames.Copy Destination:=.Range("H10")

End With
```

Comment: Regardless who answered first, your comments are very helpful.  Thanks.